# tomcat stay service status:starting, can't acess throught localhost: port(Googled, seems none has met this situation before)

Tags: tomcat

here is the weird situation:
my tomcat 7 server runs work before, but today when i want to use it, i use "configure tomcat" to start tomcat, after i clicked the start button,  all status button goes to grey, and also i checked on the services, the status of tomcat is starting, and i can't access localhost:8080, i tried to restart and reinstall tomcat 7 several times, and change the port numbers, still the same problem. And then i installed tomcat 6, and to see if the problem can be solved, but still don't.....
PS: In eclipse, i still can start tomcat, and access localhost:8080 and run *.jsp file.

Comment: Which OS? `configure tomcat` sounds like Linux, but that wouldn't make any sense...

Comment: On windows xp, use the "configure tomcat" from start up menu

Answer (score 0):

In order to start tomcat, open a console in the bin directory and run `catalina run` or, if you want to attach a debugger, use `catalina jpda run`. Errors messages, if any, should appear in the console or in one of the log files.

Comment: can you explain what does the tomcat status: starting mean?

Comment: Usually it means, that the startup went wrong and Windows (as usual) didn't notice anything... For development purposes I would strongly suggest to use the console to control Tomcat.